# Why the mod is repeatedly editing harmless content from my question without consent?

Tags: discussion, moderators, editing, closed-questions

A moderator originally had closed my [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/22537/revisions) as "opinion based". But it was reopened by other members. Even after that, this question was repeatedly edited and rolled back by the same moderator, despite of me not wishing to do so. 
IMO, this is an abuse of Mod privileges and requires intervention from those concerned.

I have seen this a number of times where the mod is trying to do such things whenever a paricular Acharya is invloved. He seems to be concerned about safeguarding that Acharya and in doing so he is acting unfairly.He is selectively deleting and editing questions related to the sect/philosophy which he belongs to.

There are other such instances also. e.g. [**here**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/19911/revisions) and [**here**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/16093/revisions).

**Questions**:

1. Can a moderator rollback or edit OP's question's intent as per own wish?
2. When should a moderator close a Qn as "opinion based" single handedly?

**Update**:

Despite my post the user is again and again rolling back my question to suit his beliefs.

Comment: Yes he did delete two of my answers and one of which was un deleted as it is by another Mod. In other case, he intentionally edited some portions out the Q so as to make my answer look off-topic and eventually deleted it.. And those two were related to this acahrya in question. So, it's a clear cut case of sectarian prejudices influencing moderation. and moderation is unfair here.

Comment: The reason for content is edited or deleted by moderator (revision 5th and revision 8th) is to avoid the opinion based question I think. "Under what circumstances can an acharya or guru normally regarded as an avatara by his disciples and the general public cease to be an avatara?" is the proper question can be answered. But "Are the reasons I listed above, valid enough, for Rāmānuja to lose his status as an avatara?" would be opinion based.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69897/discussion-on-question-by-rakesh-joshi-can-a-mod-repeatedly-edit-or-rollback-op).

Comment: @Pandya _Are the reasons I listed above, valid enough, for Rāmānuja to lose his status as an avatara? would be opinion based._ -- Not every opinion-based question needs to be closed. See "Constructive subjective questions" at [this link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Specifically read the part about "insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references".

Comment: @sv. Looks like other admins were not active when i submitted my flag

Comment: @RakeshJoshi It's big mystery how flags are handled here. One mod takes down a post. Another mod reopens it. The 3rd mod is just watching, being diplomatic ("see how it goes"), stay safe or just support the other 2 mods.