# Is there a mission statement for HSE? if not, can one be provided?

Tags: support

There seems to be disagreement as to what HSE is about.

I understand from this

[Moderating for knowledge, not truth](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/moderating-for-knowledge-not-truth/1322#1322)

post that

The mission of HSE is to become a high quality reference source of **knowledge** about Hinduism.

Some posters don't seem to agree that that is the mission of HSE.

Can a mission statement be provided and the appropriateness of content determined based on that?

Answer (score 7):

> There seems to be disagreement as to what HSE is about.

The description found on [this Tour page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) is so clear that there should not exist any doubts regarding what this site is all about.

> **Hinduism Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about
> Hinduism.**
>
> It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A
> sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of
> detailed answers to every question about Hindu religion.